# Is a sustain pedal the same as a sustainer pedal?

Tags: guitar-effects, effects-pedal, keyboard-pedals, sustain

I have a sustain pedal for my keyboard. My references are talking about compressor pedals, otherwise known as sustainer pedals?

Is the sustainer pedal just the same as a sustain pedal but used for guitars, or as just a more advanced alternative for both a guitar and a keyboard?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.
A sustain pedal is a simple switch with a piece of cable attached that the keyboard uses to emulate the function of the sustain pedal on the piano - which basically means "let ring the notes when the pedal is depressed even if you lift your fingers off the keys".

A sustain*er* pedal is a compressor, which is a thing that that limits the dynamic range of the audio signal - it's a caps lock for audio.
Loud is loud and soft is loud as well.